# freewall access div location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a [freewall](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/) to create a layout. This arranges divs based on available space.

I'm trying to access the DIVs 'left' value with  `$('#div').css("left")` which isn't returning anything.

Any other way to find out where FreeWall put something, so I can tween the container so the div is in the centre?

Comment: That's the library I'm using, not the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freewall changes the Div ID. I put the id as a class, and found it that way.